# What's the correct ways of two-way binding props in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue-component, vuejs3

Here I have two components:

> msg.vue

```html
<template>
 <div>
   <input type="text" v-model="msg" />
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: "msg",
 props: ["msg"]
};
</script>
```

> samples.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ msg }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "samples",
  props: ["msg"]
};
</script>
```

and finally,

> App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <samples v-bind:msg="msg"></samples>
    <msg :msg="msg"></msg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import samples from "./components/samples.vue";
import msg from "./components/msg.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    samples,
    msg
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      msg: "Hello World"
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Poppins", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

The thing I want to do is with the `msg` component I want to change the `msg` component in the data of App.vue. But when I change the value, Vue warns this :

[image: Vue errors]

So I can't understand what to do next. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** What's `v-model`?

```
<input v-model="msg" />
```

basically will transpile to

```
<input :value="msg" @input="msg = $event.target.value" />
```

**2.** `data` vs `props`

2.1 `data` is supposed to be component self-contained, whereas `props` is passed from parents.
2.2 `data` should be mutable within the component, `props` shouldn't. Why? Because of 2.1.

**3.**  [mutating a prop locally is considered an anti-pattern in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated)

---

**Result:** Here's the solution that I changed **only 2 lines of code** from yours:

> App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <samples v-bind:msg="msg"></samples>
    <msg :msg="msg" @update:msg="msg = $event"></msg> // changed this line
  </div>
</template>
```

> msg.vue

```html
<template>
 <div>
   <input type="text" :value="msg" @input="$emit('uddate:msg', $event.target.value)" /> // changed this line
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the most documented answer, @Loi Nguyen Huynh!!

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd You're welcome, I also learned a lot along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply not allowed to mutate props, you're only allowed to change `data` variables.

To fix your problem here's what you could do. Implement a `v-model` on the component, so the `msg` always stays in sync, also in the `App`

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <samples v-bind:msg="msg"></samples>
    <msg v-model="msg"></msg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import samples from "./components/samples.vue";
import msg from "./components/msg.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    samples,
    msg
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      msg: "Hello World"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

msg.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
   <input type="text" v-model="selected" />
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: "msg",
 props: ["value"],
 computed: {
   selected: {
     get() {
       return this.value;
     },
     set(value) {
       return this.$emit('input', value)
     }
   }
 }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `v-model` instead use `$emit`

**Msg Component**

```
      Vue.component('msg',{
        props:["msg"],
        template: `<div>
          <input @keyup="changeMsg" :value="msg">
        </div>`,
        methods:{
          changeMsg:function(e){
            this.$emit("changed",e.target.value);
          }
        }
      });


    <msg @changed="msg = $event" :msg="msg"></msg>
```

**[Check Solution in CodePen](https://codepen.io/tech-49/pen/vYExjbO?editors=1010)**

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use [v-bind.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier). Follow the link to see the document and usage. By using this, you need to change **2 lines of code from yours** to make it work:

In *App.vue*:

```html
change
<msg :msg="msg"></msg>
to
<msg :msg.sync="msg"></msg>
```

In *msg.vue*:

```html
change
<input type="text" v-model="msg" />
to
<input type="text" @input="$emit('update:msg',$event.target.value)" />
```

However, this one is [not recommended by Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed)